# Stream byte[] or file from RIA service to Silverlight client

Tags: silverlight, ria

I am looking for a good example or best practice of streaming bytes from RIA service retrieved by a SL4 of SL5 client.  The idea is the SL client needs to download a file generated within the RIA service.

Preferably, I would like to open a regular byte stream in RIA and have it download to the client.

Any good examples out there?

Answer (score 2):

I use this code ,but i don't know, What is the best solution

Server Side

```
  public string GetUserPhoto(string Username)
           {
             byte[] Photo = DomainController.GetUserPhoto(Username);

             StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(Photo.Length * 2);
             foreach (byte b in Photo)
               hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
             return hex.ToString();

           }
```

Client Side

```
InvokeOperation<string> InvokeOp = context.GetUserPhoto(username);
        InvokeOp.Completed += (s, e) =>
          {
            if (!InvokeOp.HasError)
            {
              string photo = ((InvokeOperation<string>)s).Value;

              int NumberChars = photo.Length; 
              byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2]; 
              for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(photo.Substring(i, 2), 16);

              _UserPhoto = bytes;

              onPropertyChanged("UserPhoto");
            }
          };
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand I could simply just return bytes or a string to a client and have the client use the content the way it wants, or to create a file, etc.  I guess I am wondering how I could do these so that I could stream the byttes from server to client and have the client process the bytes as they come in in chunks.  I don't see any native way to do this with RIA unless I am missing something.